# Not able to save product new date in Magento

Tags: magento

We are implementing a small functionality to change the product's new "from" and "to" date. To implement the same, we are taking both date via user input in format like "m/d/Y". But these dates are not saving for any type of product.

We have tried many times, but each time got failed.

Following are the solutions, we have tries to save the dates:

Suppose our product's new "from" and "to" date are 03/30/2015 and 04/05/2015 respectively. And product id is 937. Now, we have tried as :

1st solution:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(937);  
$product->setNewsFromDate('03/30/2015');  
$product->setNewsToDate('04/05/2015');  
$product->save();
```

2nd solution:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(937);  
$product->setData('news_from_date','03/30/2015');  
$product->setData('news_to_date','04/05/2015');  
$product->save();
```

3rd solution:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(937);  
$product->setData('news_from_date','2015-03-30 00:00:00');  
$product->setData('news_to_date','2015-04-05 00:00:00');  
$product->save();
```

We have tried all the above steps but my dates are not saving for corresponding product. With the Ist point, we have saved product's special "from" and "to" date and this is working fine but not in case of product's new date.

Can anyone please help, how can we save the new date? Are we doing something wrong in above solutions as result dates are not saving?

Waiting for solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a standalone external file or customize it to fit as needed:

```
umask(0);
Mage::app( 'admin' );

$sProductId     = 1;
$oProduct       = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load( $sProductId );
$oDate          = new Zend_Date( strtotime( 'now' ) );
$sFormattedDate = $oDate->toString( Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT );
$oProduct->setData( 'news_from_date', $sFormattedDate );
$oProduct->setData( 'news_to_date', $sFormattedDate );
$oProduct->save();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. We have tried your solution even tried with other date formats, but every time we fail.